# How to return subgraph from rdf graph

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web

I have an RDF graph G with several classes assuming for simplicity (Person and Parrot).
The class `Person` is connected to the class `Parrot` by the property `hasAnimal`, e.g.:

```
@PREFIX : <http://example.org/> 

:Hugo rdf:type :Person . 
:Hugo rdfs:label "Hugo" .
:Hugo :hasAnimal :Birdy.
:Birdy rdf:type :Parrot .
:Birdy rdfs:label :"Birdy" .

:LonleyBrido rdf:type :Parrot .
```

What is wanted is a subgraph of G that contains all the triples from Person and Parrot that are directly connected with each other, starting from Person. The initial Person does not matter to me, the important part is that only connected triples are extracted i.e. that only persons that do have a parrot or don't get outputted. What I have already tried is the following:

```
construct {
?person ?p ?o .
?parrot ?p2 ?o2 .
} where {
?person rdf:type :Person .
?person ?p ?o .
?person :hasAnimal ?parrot .
?parrot  rdf:type :Parrot  .
?parrot  ?p2 ?o2 .
}
```

So the expected output would be:

```
:Hugo rdf:type :Person . 
:Hugo rdfs:label "Hugo" .
:Hugo :hasAnimal :Birdy.
:Birdy rdf:type :Parrot .
:Birdy rdfs:label :"Birdy" .
```

I am executing this query on a `rdflib` graph.
Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: please provide sample data in N-Triples or Turtle syntax - if the query returns an empty set of triples, then the query simply doesn't match the data. Check prefixes, check naming of classes and properties, check if there is any triple connecting instances of `:A` to instances of `:B` via a predicate `:a_to_b`

Comment: Like I created minimal sample data: `PREFIX : <http://example.org/>

:a a :A .
:a :a_to_b :b .
:b a :B .` - and the query obviously works (using the same namespace for `:` in your query)

Comment: your sample data and query are not fully syntactically correct. Anyways, the fixed self-contained data: `@prefix : <http://example.org/> . 
@prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>.
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.


:Hugo rdf:type :Person . 
:Hugo rdfs:label "Hugo" .
:Hugo :hasAnimal :Birdy.
:Birdy rdf:type :Parrot .
:Birdy rdfs:label "Birdy" .

:LonleyBrido rdf:type :Parrot .`

Comment: and query: `PREFIX : <http://example.org/>
PREFIX rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

construct {
?person ?p ?o .
?parrot ?p2 ?o2 .
} where {
?person rdf:type :Person .
?person ?p ?o .
?person :hasAnimal ?parrot .
?parrot  rdf:type :Parrot  .
?parrot  ?p2 ?o2 .
}`

Comment: running the query on the data the result is not empty, so I do not understand your issue here? (I used Apache Jena CLI for running the query on the data)

Comment: If `rdflib` doesn't work, then you should show the code. Maybe you did something wrong in the Python code, please show it here

Comment: Actually you are right that i were right. Seems my code works fine. I just checked my turtle file and it seems that while i do convert it from csv the uri's geht messed up. Anyways, thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is already described above:

```py
import rdflib
from rdflib.namespace import RDF, RDFS

query = """
construct {
?person ?p ?o .
?parrot ?p2 ?o2 .
} where {
?person rdf:type :Person .
?person ?p ?o .
?person :hasAnimal ?parrot .
?parrot  rdf:type :Parrot  .
?parrot  ?p2 ?o2 .
}
"""

g = rdflib.Graph()
g.parse("example.ttl", format="ttl")
g.bind("rdf", RDF)
g.bind("rdfs", RDFS)
EX= rdflib.Namespace("http://example.org/")
g.bind("example", EX)
result = g.query(query)
```